# CompileError with inherited parameter in sql-alchemy table class

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I Have a SQLalchemy class (flask-sqlalchemy) which inherits from another class and looks like this

```
class Cat(db.Model, Category):
    __tablename__ = 'Cat'
    id = db.Column(db.String(1000), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.String(1000), db.ForeignKey('SocArxivCategory.id'))

    parent_category = db.relationship('Cat',
                                      backref=db.backref('children',
                                                         order_by=Category.name,
                                                         lazy='selectin'),
                                      remote_side='Cat.id')
```

and the parent class is

```
class Category():
    __tablename__ = 'Category'
    name = db.Column(db.String(2000), nullable=False)
```

You see that the Cat table builds a relationship using the Category.name attribute. But this seems to cause an error

```
....
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 692, in _fallback_column_name
    raise exc.CompileError("Cannot compile Column object until "
CompileError: Cannot compile Column object until its 'name' is assigned.
```

so it seems to try to build the relationship before inheriting the name attribute? I am not sure whether this is an SQLalchemy issue or a Python issue? Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok after a bit of searching and more consulting of the sqlalchemy docs I found a solution. Changing the definition of the relationship to

```
parent_category = db.relationship('Cat',
                                  backref=db.backref('children',
                                                     order_by=lambda: Cat.name,
                                                     lazy='selectin'),
                                  remote_side='Cat.id')
```

did the trick

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the only thing you changed was using a function in `order_by`?